# hash-like string shortener with decoder

Tags: python, string

I have a really long string that I want to shorten into a smaller string of random characters similar to what a hash does. However, I want to be able to undo it later to read it. As far as I know hashes are unable to be undone and thus I could not read it later.

Comment: Maybe try run length or huffman encoding. Although I doubt you'll get a large reduction in size with those methods.

Comment: You would need a database, mapping your short strings (which could be hashes, sequentially assigned, or purely random) back to the original strings.

Comment: Rather than 'encoding' or 'hashing', you're looking to 'compress'. There's many ways to compress data using Python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a database and just stuck with the long strings. Originally, I was going to shorten them and not have a database, but I think a database is better anyways and it allows me to store the long form.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's builtin compression library `zlib`

```
>>> from zlib import compress, decompress
>>> original = 'A' * 1024
>>> len(original)
1024
>>> compressed = compress(original.encode('utf-8'))
>>> len(compressed)
17
>>> original == decompress(compressed).decode('utf-8')
True
```

Note that the original string must contain some patterns to be compressed efficiently. In general, the more [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) `original` has, the longer `compressed` will be.